# UserControl binding to itself

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I have created a large `UserControl`, and for the testing purpose, I had set the `BindingContext = this`. Now I need a `BindableProperty`, so I can not use this trick anymore, so how can I set it to reflect itself?
The problem is, that I am using the UserControl in XAML, and then it say, the element binded for SelectedDate does not exist, when I set `BindingContext = this`.

The `UserControl` is so complex, that the only thing, I can define in XAML is the main like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="ComplexUserControl" />
```

Which I do not find the right way to go

I have created a simple UserControl, so you can see, what I am trying to do

```
class Test : Grid
{
   public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedDateProperty = BindableProperty.Create("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(Test), defaultValue: DateTime.Now, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

   public DateTime Date1
   {
      get { return DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1); }
   }

   public DateTime Date2
   {
      get { return DateTime.Today; }
   }

   public DateTime Date3
   {
      get { return DateTime.Today.AddDays(1); }
   }

   public Test()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void InitializeComponent()
   {
      ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
      ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
      ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

      Button btn1 = new Button();
      btn1.SetBinding(Button.FontSizeProperty, new Binding("SelectedDate", converter: new IsSelectedFontSizeConverter(), converterParameter: Date1));
      btn1.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, new Binding("Date1", stringFormat: "dd"));
      Children.Add(btn1, 0, 0);

      Button btn2 = new Button();
      btn2.SetBinding(Button.FontSizeProperty, new Binding("SelectedDate", converter: new IsSelectedFontSizeConverter(), converterParameter: Date2));
      btn2.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, new Binding("Date2", stringFormat: "dd"));
      Children.Add(btn2, 1, 0);

      Button btn3 = new Button();
      btn3.SetBinding(Button.FontSizeProperty, new Binding("SelectedDate", converter: new IsSelectedFontSizeConverter(), converterParameter: Date3));
      btn3.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, new Binding("Date3", stringFormat: "dd"));
      Children.Add(btn3, 2, 0);
   }
}
```

It shall be possible from the outside to set the SelectedDate to another Date.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Using x:Reference.

```
<Button Text="{Binding Date3,Source={x:Reference testControl}"
        FontSize="{Binding SelectedDate, Converter={StaticResource myConverter},
             ConverterParameter={Binding Date3,Source={x:Reference testControl}}}" />
```

Below link help you to understand this concept.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/

Comment: How can I set the `testcontrol` in c# code? As I cannot create the UserControl in XAML (too much calculation is going on in the UserControl to do in XAML)?

Comment: You have to set x:name="testControl" of your control.
Create test.xaml page.

<Grid x:Class="myNamespace.Test" x:Name="testControl"

Comment: As I see, you can only do it in xaml

Comment: Ya, I dont know how to achieve this by code.
I had same issue and I fixed by this method.

Comment: Then I have to create the UserControl as a xaml, where the only thing I can define is the Grid :o

Comment: You have to remove BindingContext = this, then it will work fine.

Comment: No, it does not. That's what I am doing at the moment, where it can not show the content from Dates, as it looks in the ViewModel for the page.

Comment: I think you missed to assign BindingContext to parent control or test control.
parentControl.BindingContext = myViewModel; Please check it once.